# Best method to get all unchanged text box in win form to store it as null

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just new one in programming with C#, and try to make win form with some controls like

Item code
Item name
Item price
Pack name

.. etc

and i have stored procedure to insert data

so i send this controls to SP as is types
but my problem is most of this data optional so maybe text box get some data or not

i need best way to get unchanged text box as null to send it null to database
however is it

Text         (string)
Number       (int)

I added this line

```
parm[6].Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pack_name) ? null : pack_name;
```

is it good to repeat this line for each parameter
is there a way to do all of this in one step

and what about int values

Comment: it all depends on what you consider null/empty. is 0 = null ? empty string = null ?

Comment: Ok
but is it right to repeat check for each parameter line like above

Is there a way to get null of all if unchanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. One of the best ways is binding the textbox controls to nullable properties of a class:

   public string? firstName {get;set;}

In the setters check for string.Empty and set the property to null.

*You will want your stored procedure to allow Null parameters and have db table columns that are nullable or have a default value.*

*By having all the methods, classes and properties in a business logic project that facilitates the communication between the presentation tier and the DAL you will be able to unit test! Also doing this helps separation of concerns and fits under the 3 tiers architecture pattern.*

2. Another tip is to use controls that reflect the type of value it holds, like a UpDownNumeric input for Integers, Decimals & etc. This not only telegraph's the control type to you it  makes the user interface more intuitive.
3. See this QA for more info and **[how you can iterate through control collections for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701247/dynamic-code-snippet-c-sharp-visual-studio)**.
4. You could probably combine all the above information into one elegant solution, an Extension Method. Like a method that extends a **TextBoxBase** control with a method GetNullableValue() that contains the logic to return a value or null depending on conditions.

Comment: Can make a simple example i'm so complicated,

If create an array with 2 columns

string [,] and and add on event text changed

to check what happen and add the result to this array

for example

pack_name text box the user add data and the event check this data

after that
add this data to my array
by 
text_box name
text_box text

and son on for each object text box

Comment: Just keep what you're doing `parm[6].Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pack_name) ? null : pack_name;` for each textbox. Later on when you have hundreds to worry about then bother about using the methods I've described above. ps Sorry but I cant understand your comment, I think you are getting more confused, so keep what your doing and keep it very simple